# Compass Susy table layout to display the desktop layout

Tags: susy-compass

I have a site that I themed using the compass susy tool. So far so good. Now my client wants the iPad and device like it to display the desktop layout instead of a table layout (mobile layout is ok)

My current susy layouts:

```
$mobile: 4 44em;
$desk: 45em 12;
```

The issue I am having is that since I am using the magic grids the desktop layout look squeezed in the tablets.

I would like for the desktop layout to be view in tablet as a regular site not using any responsive grid or method that automatically zoom in or out and everything to fit on the screen proportionally.

**Note:** After thinking a bit more about the issue, I think I need to include the viewport for the mobile site, but not for the tablet or desktop.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to update the viewport. Then simply set a min-width on the desktop container at whatever size you want it to stop shrinking:

```
.container {
  @include at-breakpoint($desk) {
    min-width: 55em;
  }
}
```

(I don't know your code, of course. But you can adapt that as needed.)

Comment: Thank you Eric for your answer, it fix 90% of the issue. I just have now to figure out how to turn off and on the viewport base on the screen size. Any ideas?